# Issue with Crystal Runtime silent install

Tags: crystal-reports, installshield, installshield-2018

i have added crystal runtime as a prerequisite in my installshield project. i am using the command line arguments /qn /norestart to install the runtime silently. Problem that i am facing is that if there is an older version of crystal runtime already installed on the machine then the silent installation of new version is failing.

However if I run the MSI interactively then it asks user to continue with the process and if they continue then the old verison will be unistalled once getting user consent.

can anyone tell me what changes i need to do to the install shield in order to successfully install latest runtime silently? below is a screenshot of the install shield prerequisite
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering , Solution is to use upgrade=1 parameter which removes the old run time and will install the new one

```
msiexec /package CRRuntime.msi upgrade =1 /qn
```

for installshield just add below in the commands section

```
upgrade =1 /qn
```